# Angular 2 change page title through service

Tags: angular, page-title

I have a page component which loads content through a service. The page title is currently set in ngOnInit but I would like to change it to set the page title with data received through the service. The JSON received by the service has a "title" field with the string for the page title.

Right now the code looks like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { GetPageService } from '../shared/get-page/get-page.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-capabilities',
    templateUrl: './capabilities.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./capabilities.component.scss']
})
export class CapabilitiesComponent implements OnInit {

    data: any[] = [];
    errorMessage: string;

    constructor(
        private titleService: Title,
        public getPageService: GetPageService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getPage();
        // line below should be replaced so that title come from getPage data
        this.titleService.setTitle('Sample Page Title');
    }

    getPage() {
        this.getPageService.getPage('capabilities')
            .subscribe(
                data => this.data = data,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );

    }

}
```

I have tried attaching a function to subscribe but so far I am just getting errors. Any hints pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the title from within the `subscribe()`:

```ts
getPage() {
    this.getPageService.getPage('capabilities')
        .subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
              this.data = data;
              // Set the title here.
              this.titleService.setTitle(data.title);  // Or data['title']
            },
            error => console.error(error)
        );

}
```

Comment: Thanks AF. This allows me to access the titleService but still generates an error:
Property 'title' does not exist on type 'string[]'

If I console log the var data right after "this.data = data;" it shows as an object. So I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Can you please show what the object that you log contains?

Comment: The object returned is: {title: "Capabilities Page title", heading: "Capabilities", content: "<p>Content here.</p>"}  When I change data.title to data['title'] it works. Thank you for your help with this.

Comment: Alright, good news! That was probably a TypeScript issue. In the subscribe, if you add the `any` type to `data`, it should solve the issue (I have updated the answer).